# Webrtc First track can't play

Tags: reactjs, express, webrtc

I create a conference web app by using webrtc, the client sends the track to the server by addTrack(track) and server gives that track to the others.

1. But I don't know why when I open a tab to send some tracks, the first track send to the server can not be played, and I open the second tab, the first track can play normally by others.
2. And sometimes the ID of the track change when the client sends it to the server, so that I can't Identify that track pertains to who. I have to resend that track until it not changing ID

Sending tracks **client -> server**

Client

```
        peer.onnegotiationneeded = async () =>{
            const offer = await peer.createOffer();
            await peer.setLocalDescription(offer);
        
            const sdp = peer.localDescription;
            socket.emit("negotiation", sdp);
        
            socket.off("negotiation-returned");
            socket.on("negotiation-returned", async (remoteSdp) => {
                const desc = new RTCSessionDescription(remoteSdp);
                peer.setRemoteDescription(desc).catch((e) => console.log(e));
            });
        }

/// sending function
        tracks.forEach((track) => {       
            let exist : boolean = false;
            peer?.getSenders().forEach((sender) => {
                if(sender?.track?.id === track.id){
                    exist = true
                }
            })
            if(!exist){
                console.log("add track "+track.kind,track.id)
                peer.addTrack(track);
            }
        })
```

Server

```
 peer.ontrack = (e) => {
                const track = e.track;
                onAddTrack(track)
               
            };
 socket.on("negotiation", async (clientSdp: any) => {
                const desc = new webrtc.RTCSessionDescription(clientSdp);
                await peer.setRemoteDescription(desc);

                const answer = await peer.createAnswer();
                await peer.setLocalDescription(answer);
                const serverSdp = peer.localDescription;
                socket.emit("negotiation-returned", serverSdp);
            });
```

**Receive tracks (Server-> client)**

Client

```
// negotiation
socket.on("others-negotiation", async (serverSdp: any) => {
            const desc = new RTCSessionDescription(serverSdp);
            await peer.setRemoteDescription(desc);
    
            const answer = await peer.createAnswer();
            await peer.setLocalDescription(answer);
            const clientSdp = peer.localDescription;
            socket.emit("others-negotiation-returned", clientSdp);
        });

//on server send track
peer.ontrack = (e) =>{
            console.log("get track",e.track)
            const track = e.track;
            if(track){
                track.onmute = () =>{
                    console.error("track remove id",track.id)
                    dispatch(actions.otherPeers.removeTrack(track.id))
                }
                dispatch(actions.otherPeers.addTrack(track))
            }
// function request tracks
 socket.emit("request-streams")
```

Server

```
// negotiation to sending 
peer.onnegotiationneeded = async () => {
                console.log("onnegotiationneeded");
                const offer = await peer.createOffer();
                await peer.setLocalDescription(offer);

                const sdp = peer.localDescription;

                socket.emit("others-negotiation", sdp);
            };
socket.on("others-negotiation-returned", async (remoteSdp: any) => {
                const desc = new webrtc.RTCSessionDescription(remoteSdp);
                peer.setRemoteDescription(desc).catch((e) => console.log(e));
            });

// add track to peer connection
socket.on("request-streams", () => {
                tracks.forEach((track) => {
                    if (!trackExistedSender(track.id)) {
                        peer.addTrack(track);
                    }
                });
            });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Frist track can't play in webrtc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68886444/frist-track-cant-play-in-webrtc)

Comment: That also my question, it closed and I can't reopen it so I ask again